# How to draw a star in Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, awt

I have troubles when it comes to GUI in Java. I want to write a program that will ask me to draw a star in the center of the screen, but before it will draw it I want it to ask me how much I want the stars to have arms. This code I made is just drawing a star without  anything else (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkxoV.png)

so I have to modify it (maybe some custom sort of Scanner asking me for the numbers of arms), but I'm not that good at GUI and Java. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

public class App extends Frame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new App();
    }

    public App()
    {
        setSize(540, 380);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
        g2.setStroke (new BasicStroke (15.0f)); 

        Rectangle r = getBounds(); 
        float width = 166; 
        float height = 166; 

        g2.translate( r.getWidth() / 2 - width/2, r.getHeight() / 2 - height/2); 

        Path2D star = new Path2D.Float (); 
        star.moveTo (width/5F, height-1); 
        star.lineTo (width/2F, 0); 
        star.lineTo (4*width/5F, height-1); 
        star.lineTo (0, 2*height/5F); 
        star.lineTo (width-1, 2*height/5F); 
        star.closePath (); 
        g2.draw (star); 
        g2.fill (star);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to read about layout managers and document listeners look at this code, it uses a null layout manager which is not recommended but works fine here. in order to get the value from the text box you will need to add fields to the drawpanel and set them from insertUpdate event

```
    package star;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
    import java.util.Random;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

    public class StarApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StarApp();
    }
    StarFrame sf = new StarFrame();
    public StarApp() {
    }

    public class StarFrame extends JFrame implements DocumentListener {

        StarDrawPanel drawpanel = new StarDrawPanel();
        StarInputPanel inputpanel = new StarInputPanel();

        public StarFrame () {
            inputpanel.input.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);   
            this.setLayout(null);
            this.add(inputpanel);
            this.add(drawpanel);
            drawpanel.setSize(540, 360);
            setSize(540, 380);
            inputpanel.setSize(50,30);
            setVisible(true);
        }
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {          
            drawpanel.repaint();
        }
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        }
    }

    public class StarDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        Random rand = new Random();
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
            g2.setStroke (new BasicStroke (15.0f)); 
            Rectangle r = getBounds(); 
            float width = 166; 
            float height = 166; 
            g2.translate( r.getWidth() / 2 - width/2, r.getHeight() / 2 - height/2); 
            Path2D star = new Path2D.Float (); 
            star.moveTo (width/5F, height-1); 
            star.lineTo (width/2F, 0); 
            star.lineTo (4*width/5F, height-1); 
            star.lineTo (0, 2*height/5F); 
            star.lineTo (width-1, 2*height/5F); 
            star.closePath (); 
            g2.draw (star); 
            float rc = rand.nextFloat();
            float gc = rand.nextFloat();
            float bc = rand.nextFloat();
            Color randomColor = new Color(rc, gc, bc);
            g2.setPaint(randomColor);
            g2.fill (star);
        }
    }

    public class StarInputPanel extends JPanel {
        public JTextField input = new JTextField(4);
        public StarInputPanel() {
            this.add(input);
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. How can add more arms to the Star? For example I type in the box "10" and the Star will have 10 arms. What do I need to add to the code?

Comment: in order to get the value from the text box you will need to add fields to the drawpanel and set them from insertUpdate event